# Is it necessary to delete an object if that runs on a QThread if finished signal of QThread is connected to deleteLater?

Tags: c++, qt, qthread

So I have the following code in the constructor.

```
m_someObject = new SomeObject();
m_someObject->moveToThread(&m_thread);
m_thread.start();

connect(&m_thread, &QThread::finished, m_someObject, &QObject::deleteLater);
```

Any I have the following code in the destructor.

```
 m_thread.terminate();
 while (m_thread.isRunning())
 {
 }
```

Do I still have to delete `m_someObject` despite having finished of `m_thread` connected to `deleteLater` slot of `m_someObject`?

Comment: What makes you think `m_someObject` would not be deleted? This looks good to me.

Comment: Because the destructor of `m_someObject` is never getting called. 
@RickPat

Comment: maybe try to replace `while (m_thread.isRunning())` with `m_thread.wait()`

Comment: `m_thread.terminate();` kills the thread. You should not call it. The documentation states this: ***Warning: This function is dangerous and its use is discouraged. The thread can be terminated at any point in its code path. Threads can be terminated while modifying data. There is no chance for the thread to clean up after itself, unlock any held mutexes, etc. In short, use this function only if absolutely necessary.***

Comment: true, replace the code with `m_thread.quit(); m_thread.wait();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not necessary. The connection should do exactly what you want as long as the thread does emit finished eventually. See the following Code:

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QThread>
#include <iostream>

class Test : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Test(){
        std::cout <<"c'tor" << std::endl;
    }
    ~Test(){
        std::cout << "d'tor" << std::endl;
    }
};

void startThread(){
    QThread* thr = new QThread();
    Test* test = new Test();
    connect(thr, &QThread::finished, test, &QObject::deleteLater);
    test->moveToThread( thr );
    thr->start();
    thr->quit();
    thr->wait();
    delete thr;
}
```

The output is as expected:

```
c'tor
d'tor
```

Note that the snippet wont compile right away since its missing a main.